# Normal subgroup is a quotient

Tags: group-theory

If $M, N$ - normal subgroups of a group $G$, is it true that one can always find a normal sugbroup $L \leq G$, such that $M=LN/N$?

Edit: One more condition: $G= G^{'} /N$ for some $G^{'}$

Comment: No. Take $N=G$ for instance. The concept you are probably looking for is called "avoiding", as in "covering and avoiding properties of chief factors".

Comment: What does your edit mean? Is $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$ or of $G'$?

Comment: I am sorry, I got the whole question wrong. You are right, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G^{′}$ , $G=G^{′}/N$, then $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ iff $M=LN/N$ for some $L$ - normal subgroup of $G^{'}$. My question was meant to be about the "iff" part. Got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true.  For an explicit counterexample, consider $G=Sym(4)$, the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on 4 letters, and let $N=Alt(4)$ and $M=V_4$, the [alternating group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) and [Klein-4 group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group), respectively.  Both $M$ and $N$ are normal in $G$.  $G/N$ has cardinality 2, and so for any subgroup $L$ of $G$, we see that $|LN/N | \leq 2$.  Since $M$ has cardinality 4, there is no way $M$ can be isomorphic to $LN/N$.